# django - How to get location through browser IP

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geoip

I have a really basic django app to get weather.

I need to get user's location to show them their current location's weather. I am using GeoIP for that.

But an issue has come up that GeoIP does not have information of all the IP addresses. It returns NoneType for those IP addresses.

I want to know if there is any other precise way by which I can info about User's current latitude and longitude, like maybe browser API? It should not miss any User's location like GeoIP does.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, You can NOT get exact location of user by IP.

Some IPs of ISPs are not relevant with user location but with their IDC location.

So If you "really" want your client's location, you should use client(browser)'s GeoLocation API. (Fron-end)

What you have to do is..

1. get user location by Geolocation API
2. post user location to your server
3. return location-based information
4. update your webpage(DOM) with info.